# Css margin-top moves parent element

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a code like this:

```
<html>
<head>
....
</head>
<body>
   <div class="custom">
      ...custom stuff here...
   </div>
</body>
```

Next I have a css like this :

```
.custom{
margin-left: 45%;
margin-top: 45%;
}
```

This code is supposed to move the div always to center of the screen. The margin left works perfectly fine, and centers the div properly, but the margin-top moves the body element - which is the parent element of the div. 
If I change the units to other than % (px,em,rem) it works fine ... but with % it moves the body. I tried stuff like adding little padding/margin to parent, adding overflow and other properties inside the parent but it is still doing the same thing. The body element is moved by 45% to almost double size of my screen, so in the end the  is almost out of the screen at the bottom.

If the margin should not accept % units why is the margin-left working fine ? I don't understand this behaviour. Also elements inside div should absolutely not do anything with the parent so I am really confused right now.. Any ideas ?

Forgot to add some body definitions :

```
body{
   width: 700px;
   height: 400px;
   margin : 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   overflow: hidden;
   backgrou....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explanation

Yes, it is a correct behaviour because the percents consider parents position. Like in your example, it will be positioned 45% below of body position.

But in your example, this wont work because 45% is not the center of any screen, see your example with some borders to see the behaviour:

```css
body {
  border:1px solid red;
}

.custom{

  margin-left: 45%;
  margin-top: 45%;
  
  border:1px solid blue;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="custom">
      ...custom stuff here...
   </div>
```

There are different way to do this, you can use display:flex, or just positioning using Maths, Eg:

### Solution - Absolute elements

If you can float your element, define your element with position:absolute, so define top and left 50% and return with transform -50%, see this example.

This is nice to centerize, it works in any element with any size.

```css
.custom{

  position: absolute;
  
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  
  border:1px solid blue;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="custom">
      ...custom stuff here...
   </div>
```

Comment: Read the comment under my answer, I think your answer is the best!

Comment: Thanks Adam, i hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I get why you do not understand this behavior, it is a common question and a dilemma that keeps on showing up for everyone.

Before we dive into it, please reference [this great article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

So, because you are trying to center your `custom` div using margins alone, you are essentially not centering with respect to the page. Think about what margin does for you: it clears an area around an element. You could easily have a case where your margin is equal to the greater of the adjoining margins; this is common when working with vertical margins.

You can get around this issue in different ways, namely your approach is incorrect.

I suggest looking up the article I linked and using their solution for centering things horizontally:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Here you may add a vertical margin if you wish like so:

```
margin: 20vh auto 0 auto;
```

Let me know if you need any more assistance

Comment: This hasn't helped me, but the article is nice, thanks

Comment: @JanDoomwalkerxPeřina I believe the correct answers that you got all can be found in this article. Look at how they have multiple solutions depending on your needs. Including the - vertical and horizontal - centering with a block level element

Answer (score 2):

You are using margins, incorrectly.

Make `.content` `absolute` then place where ever you want.

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4p18mxg9/6/

```
.custom{
position: absolute;    
left: 45%;
top: 45%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me

Comment: I appreciate the up-vote, however Túlio Castro answer above mine answer your question more thoroughly. Please read his answer for an explanation of what was going on in your page, also I think you should mark his answer as being correct, i will just keep the upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a width, it will be on the center of the screen with

```
.custom {
    border: solid 1px red;
    margin: auto;
    width: 20em;
}
```

I also recommend this web [Learn CSS Layout](http://learnlayout.com/), it's all I always wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.custom {
    border: solid 1px red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  ....
</head>

<body>
  <div class="custom">
    ...custom stuff here...
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything.